# preg_replace time and date with link

Tags: php, preg-replace

Existing code I have draws a txt file and first converts http elements to links and then converts hashtag elements to links then prints the result. At the end of every text is a dash then a time and date (*DOY and YEAR with leading zero - for a reason*). The text echos on the page as (ex.)

> Blah blah blah and blah blah - 3:47:32 310 017

or time/date variations of
14:09:47 23 017
7:38:83 9 017
so there is no set figure of characters

```
$text = file_get_contents("temp.txt");
$link = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
$hash = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/m', '<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=$1" target="_blank">#$1</a>', $link);
echo $hash;
```

As an admitted novice, I have not been able to best translate the entirety of the syntax that creates the above preg_replace(s) to understand it well enough to make use of it to apply to wanting to do the same with the end time/date. I have made several attempts but have seen no results to demonstrate I am even going in the proper direction.

My thought process is that the order is

> 0?colon00colon00space0??space000

are the identities of the positions to seek.

Comment: So what do you want to happen to that date/time? Make it a hyperlink? if so, to where? Put it in bold? Remove it?

Comment: Link. It was implied in my head :)

Comment: Something like this? `$link = preg_replace('@\b([1-9]\d?:\d\d:\d\d [1-9]\d\d? 0\d\d)\b@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);`

Comment: Tested (for the current time/date) and it seems to work. I am humbled by how simple you made it look. Thx!

Comment: OK, posted as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
$link = preg_replace('@\b(\d\d?:\d\d:\d\d [1-9]\d{0,2} 0\d\d)\b@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
```

Comment: Ceased working with the time/date '0:18:27 311 017' - I suppose I shd alter the 1-9 to 0-9 ?

Comment: Also noticed and asking if the DOY shd be [1-9]\[1-9]\d? bcz it is 1 to 365 ?

Comment: The first is true: I made the change. The second should also change, making the second digit optional; I have made the change.

Comment: Since you are the go to pro - I searched for and did not find a proper syntax - what is the proper place to have this link finder as seen above in the original post '@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@' only find .org extension? That part that screws me up is \w/_\.]* because I can't seem to get it to work adding org on either side of the bracket. Thx

Comment: Add `\.org` just before `(:\d+)?`.

Comment: @(https?://([-\w\.]+)+\.org(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@  - can I ask what the colon represents in that (:\d+) ? Thx

Comment: It is a literal colon that may appear in URLs that specify a port number, like `http://localhost:80/test`.

Comment: I had not anticipated that. Thanks for your assistance.